# Is it ok to use $emit in $watch angularjs

Tags: angularjs, watch, emit

Is it ok to use $emit in $watch like this code below?

```
    $scope.$watch("IsResponseArrived", function () {
        if ($scope.IsResponseArrived) {
            if ($scope.IsAuthorize) {
                var data FillData();
                $scope.$emit("DataResponse", { retVal: data });
            }
            else {
                reset();
            }
        }
    });
```

and the parameter IsResponseArrived changes from script like this: in html page I have

```
<input type="text" id="cgResponseArrived" ng-model="IsResponseArrived" /> 
<input type="hidden" click="Fill()" /> 

<script> 
function Fill() { 
       $("#cgResponseArrived").val(true).trigger("change"); 
} 
</script>
```

and some other request is triggered the click event of the hidden input

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Yes there is no problem of using that.

Comment: Thank you for youe answer, 
but if the parameter IsResponseArrived changes from script like this:
in html page I have

<input type="text" id="cgResponseArrived" ng-model="IsResponseArrived" />
<input type="hidden" click="Fill()" />

<script>
 function Fill() {
        $("#cgResponseArrived").val(true).trigger("change");
}
</script>

and some other request is triggered the click event of the hidden input

Comment: I suggest you put ^ in your question or post a new question

Comment: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14994391/1139099) question before solving the problem